# Verification of Data String Integrity based on base-line formula

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need some help kick starting a way to verify the integrity of Strings that appear in a particular field for ALL records of a Table:

Table Alpha:

```
| A-ID* |        Description**         |        Formula**         |
|-------|------------------------------|--------------------------|
| A101  | House + 2 bed + 1 bath       | TYPH + numbdB + numbathA |
| A212  | Apartment + 1 bed + 1 bath   | TYPA + numbdA + numbathA |
| A342  | Condominium + 4 bed + 3 bath | TYPC + numbdC + numbathZ |
```

*Primary Key; fixed length
**Variable length

Now the items that make up the "Description" (Table Alpha [above]) are found in separate tables:

Table Bravo:

```
| Housing_ID* | HousingDes** |
|-------------|--------------|
| TYPH        | House        |
| TYPA        | Apartment    |
| TYPC        | Condominium  |
```

Table Charlie:

```
| Room_ID* | RoomDes** |
|----------|-----------|
| numbdA   | 1 bed     |
| numbdB   | 2 bed     |
| numbdC   | 4 bed     |
```

Table Delta:

```
| Bath_ID* | BathDes** |
|----------|-----------|
| numbathA | 1 bath    |
| numbathZ | 3 bath    |
```

*Primary Key; fixed length
**Variable length

Now, I need a way to verify that the "Description" of a record (Table Alpha) is consistent with the associated "Formula" (Table Alpha) as specified by the Tables Bravo – Delta. For example, with regard to Record 1 of Table Alpha, the "Description" of a record could be inadvertently modified. How could I "flag" this incorrect record?

```
| A-ID* |       Description**        |        Formula**         |
|-------|----------------------------|--------------------------|
| A101  | House"ee" + 2 bed + 1 bath | TYPH + numbdB + numbathA |
```

**How do I recreate Table Alpha [let’s call this new table, Table FormAlphaBuild] based on the "Formulas" only?** For each "A-ID," I could then compare the "Description" found in Table Alpha to the "Description" found in Table FormAlphaBuild, and then query this discrepancy so I know which records need to be corrected.

Any input would be appreciated. My thoughts are as follows:

```
    Private Sub VerifyDescription_Click ()

        Dim dbHouse As Database
        Dim rsAlp, rsFAB As Recordset
        Dim Description, Formula, Housing_ID, Room_ID, Bath_ID As String

        Set dbhouse = CurrentDb
        Set rsFAB = dbs.OpenRecordSet ("Table_FormAlphaBuild")
        Set rsAlp = dbs.OpenRecordSet ("Table_Alpha")


        rsAlp.MoveLast
        rsAlp.MoveFirst

        Do Until rsAlp.EOF
            rsFAB.AddNew
                rsFAB![A-ID] = rsAlp![A-ID]
                rsFAB![Formula] = rsAlp![Formula]
        rsFAB.Update
        rsAlp.MoveNext
        Loop

        rsFAB.MoveLast
        rsFAB.MoveFirst

        Do Until rsFAB.EOF
            Housing_ID = Mid(rsFAB![Formula], 1, 4)
            Room_ID = Mid(rsFAB![Formula], 5, 6)
            Bath_ID = Mid(rsFAB![Formula], 9)

 Description = DLookup("HousingDes", "Table_Bravo") "+" DLookup("RoomDes",  "Table_Charlie") "+" DLookup("BathDes", "Table_Delta") & Mid(Bath_ID, x, 8)
```

How could I account for a variable number of bathroom_IDs? They would always  come after a single Housing_ID + Room_ID.

Some insight please—how to list the proper description for EACH "A-ID".

I need help with creating the FormAlphaBuild table. Once I have this, I think I can go about coming up with a mechanism for comparing the Alpha "Description" against the FormAlphaBuild "Description".

Comment: Please use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to show the sample data in tabular form instead of lists. And please get rid of the typographic quotes `“”` and use standard quotes `""` instead (double+single quotes).

Comment: Thank you, Andre. I've updated my initial post accordingly.

Comment: It might be worth revisiting your database schema (structure). Generally, it's not a good idea to combine multiple pieces of information into a single column. For example, you can separate your data into three columns: type of house (possibly a key to look up in the plain-English name in another table), number of beds, and number of baths. Then you can make a query using that information to write a plain-English description in any format you like. For more reading, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

Will Jobs talks perfect sense about redesigning your database structure in the way he suggests.
Maybe that is the ultimate goal of your process?

To verify the integrity of your Description string ask yourself, does this process need to be easily repeatable one a regular basis? In which case you'll need some nice code.

If it is just a one off process to clean up the data and hopefully follow Will Jobs' database structure advice then I would just use a few queries and filters in Accesses user interface.

I personally find it helpful to see my workings in a table structureand access is great for this.

To go this route, create a query based on your Alpha table using some string functions on your Description string.

```
decriptionStringIntegrity: iif(lcase(trim([Description])) Like "[a-z]* + #* bed + #* bath","good","bad")

propertyType: Trim(Left([Description],InStr([Description]," + ")))

bedroomCount: Trim(Left(Mid([Description],InStr([Description],"+")+2),InStr(Mid([Description],InStr([Description],"+")+2)," ")))

bathroomCount: Trim(Replace(Mid([Description],InStr([Description],"bed + ")+5,30),"bath",""))
```

There is quite a lot going on there but if you break each down into smaller chunks it is quite easy to understand.

In Access's query view you can filter this further by only showing “bad” decriptionStringIntegrity or blank bedroomCount etc.
This is not very robust but it will at least show you most of the "bad" Descriptions such as spelling errors and missing delimiters ( the plus + character ).

You may even want to run an initial clean up of the description string by removing double spaces and ensuring each “+” is surrounded by a space.

Make sure to do all this in a copy of the database, easy to do with access, just copy the file, no excuse not to.

Here is a query string which does the job on your example data.

```
SELECT Alpha.Description, IIf(LCase(Trim([Description])) Like "[a-z]* + #* bed + #* bath","good","bad") AS decriptionStringIntegrity, Trim(Left([Description],InStr([Description]," + "))) AS propertyType, Trim(Left(Mid([Description],InStr([Description],"+")+2),InStr(Mid([Description],InStr([Description],"+")+2)," "))) AS bedroomCount, Trim(Replace(Mid([Description],InStr([Description],"bed + ")+5,30),"bath","")) AS bathroomCount
FROM Alpha;
```

Hope that helps